# Query boost depending on actual field value

Tags: boost, elasticsearch

Hi StackOverflowcrowd,

iam currently working on  elasticsearch for my website. My question is:
Is it possible to boost an query depending on the value of a field.

Example:
I have a field called premiumlevel. If the "Datarow" contains a premiumlevel of 4 the boostvalue shall be 40 if it is 3 the boostvalue shall be 30 and so on.
Boost = fieldvalue multiplied by 10

Is there a way to realize a query like this? I saw a way to a similiar query for dates with range but I never found an example where the actual value of the field is used for the boost value calculation.

#### Edit:

I think I just found the solution for my question.
If I get the Documentation right it might be possible to achieve my goal with CustomScore Queries. I will edit this answer with my codesnippet after I have testet it completly.

This is the Documentationparagraph:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-score-query.html

P.S.: The rule that new users are not allowed to answer their own questions before 8 hours have passed is not logical/productive in my honest opinion.

Comment: You are on the right track: you just need to use a little script to customize the score.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do what you want would be to actually index the boost value:

From the doc: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/boost-field.html

```
{
  "tweet" : {
    "_boost" : {"name" : "_boost", "null_value" : 1.0}
  }
}
```

> The above mapping defines mapping for a field named _boost. If the _boost field exists within the JSON document indexed, its value will control the boost level of the document indexed.

Comment: I dont think that this approach can solve my problem but I found another possible solution(See my edit, i couldnt answer myself because  Iam a new User)